# People API: Cannot overcome error: rateLimitExceeded: Resource has been exhausted

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-api-ruby-client, google-people-api

I'm using [Google API Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client) (ruby)  to access the People API and create/update my Google Contacts. I've  successfully authenticated using a OAuth 2.0 flow, and have managed to use the API's methods to create new contacts.

It's been a few days that I've hit a brick wall and cannot create any new contacts. All API calls fail with the following response:

`ERROR: #<Google::Apis::RateLimitError: rateLimitExceeded: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota). status_code: 429`

**I've intentionally left 24h to go by**, but as soon as I try to use the people.createContact method, I get the same error message. Here's a screenshot of the Project's metrics, showing that I've only done 20 read and just 3 write requests within one hour, and all 3 write requests fail with this error [image: Project metrics]

Under no circumstances I've gone above the 90 requests per minute that the People API Quota page mentions.

I also get the same error message when I use the API Explorer interface to call the create method using curl:
[image: API Explorer same error]

**Can anyone help? What is the quota that I'm maxing out?**

I'd appreciate any help on this,
Thanks

Comment: IIR there is a limit on the number of creates per day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61895430/1841839  <- another duplicate

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, thanks for your reply!
1) What is the daily limit on creates? Where is this documented? In any case, I've tried creating a single contact in one day, and the call still failed with the same rateLimit error.
2) My total number of contacts are ~3100, far from the 25k contacts limit mentioned in the other SO question you link to
https://gmail.googleblog.com/2011/05/store-up-to-25000-contacts.html

Comment: You will need to look for the documentation im not aware of any it may be a soft rule. You would need to create a new Google account and attempt to insert into that the one your inserting into now has probably been black listed.