# Google People API createContact (429 Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota))

Tags: google-people-api

Google contacts contains 25,000 contacts.
When I try to create new contact via Google People API, the response contains `429` errors with the message:

> "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)".

How to increase the contacts limit without using another account?

Answer (score 0):

### You can try to request higher quota for Google APIs as mentioned in [Managing your quota using the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#managing_your_quota)

- Go to your GCP project
- Go to quotas
- Click `EDIT QUOTAS`
- Request higher quota

Mind that the request for higher quotas will not always be accepted.

Indeed, as you can draw from the [documentation](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/148779#size_limits):

**The maximum number of contacts in Gmail is 25000.**

So this quota is not coming from the People API or any other Google API, but from the limits of Gmail itself.

Consequently,  to create more contacts, you won't get around creating another email account - see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895430/people-api-quota-exceeded-fbs-quota-limit-exceeded) post.

Comment: Yes, I watched this post and read about the Google contact limit. But somehow, 26k contacts got into the account, after an error during creation. Can I increase my contact limit without creating an additional account, such as using a business account or additional payment?

Comment: I do believe that this limit is independent of the type of account, but you can double-check with [Google support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).